# How can I generate an array of all fields in a JSON struct instance using reflection?

Tags: arrays, json, go, struct, reflection

Let me show my code first:

This is my structure

```golang
type Lessee struct {
    Name       string    `json:"name" gorm:"name"`
    ShortName  string    `json:"shortName" gorm:"short_name"`
    Code       string    `json:"code" gorm:"code"`
    CreditCode string    `json:"creditCode" gorm:"credit_code"`
    UnitMan    string    `json:"unitMan" gorm:"unit_man"`
    UnitMobile string    `json:"unitMobile" gorm:"unit_mobile"`
    UnitEmail  string    `json:"unitEmail" gorm:"unit_email"`
    UnitPhone  string    `json:"unitPhone" gorm:"unit_phone"`
    Remark     string    `json:"remark" gorm:"remark"`
    Tenancy    int       `json:"tenancy" gorm:"tenancy"`
    BeginTime  time.Time `json:"beginTime" gorm:"begin_time"`
    EndTime    time.Time `json:"endTime" gorm:"end_time"`
    AppLimit   int       `json:"appLimit" gorm:"app_limit"`
    ManagerId  string    `json:"managerId" gorm:"manager_id"`
    CipherId   string    `json:"cipherId" gorm:"cipher_id"`
    State      int       `json:"state" gorm:"state"`
    BaseModel
}
type BaseModel struct {
    MinBaseModel
    UpdateBy   string    `json:"updateBy" gorm:"column:update_by"`
    UpdateTime time.Time `json:"updateTime" gorm:"column:update_time"`
}

type MinBaseModel struct {
    Id         string    `json:"id" gorm:"column:id;primary_key"`
    CreateBy   string    `json:"createBy" gorm:"column:create_by"`
    CreateTime time.Time `json:"createTime" gorm:"column:create_time"`
}
```

This is an example of my Lessee structure

```golang
lessee := Lessee{
        Name:       "Jayleonc Company",
        ShortName:  "Jay",
        CreditCode: "91440101MA9Y9T9K3A",
        UnitMan:    "JJ",
        UnitMobile: "13333333333",
        UnitPhone:  "020-1111111",
        UnitEmail:  "jj@gmail.com",
        Remark:     "",
        Tenancy:    14,
        AppLimit:   10,
        BeginTime:  time.Now(),
        BaseModel: BaseModel{
            UpdateTime: time.Now(),
            UpdateBy:   "Jayleonc",
            MinBaseModel: MinBaseModel{
                Id: "08fe01037faeb74ce2e82f92651c2109",
            },
        },
    }
```

As you can see, my lessee does not contain all the fields, fields like "Code", "CreateBy", etc. do not exist in the lessee instance.

Requirement: Returns an array of all the fields that appear in the lessee instance, note that the fields that exist in the lessee instance are the ones displayed, not all the fields in the Lessee structure.

I expect the result of the paragraph to be something like this:

```golang
[]string{"Name", "ShortName", "CreditCode", "UnitMan",
        "UnitMobile", "UnitEmail", "UnitPhone", "Remark", "Tenancy",
        "BeginTime", "AppLimit", "UpdateBy", "UpdateTime", "Id"}
```

The structure is not important, what matters is the requirements mentioned above.

That is, only the fields in the instance are displayed, even if the field is an empty string, like Remake = ""

I've tried using "reflect" and "encoding/json" libraries, but the structure doesn't meet my expectations because fields like "Code" in the Lessee structure will also determine if it's a zero value, but I don't need "Code", I just need Remake because "Remake" is assigned a value in the lessee instance, even if it's a zero value.

I am not sure if I am describing my problem too complicated, I hope you can understand my problem and help me.

Thanks!

Comment: *"As you can see, my lessee does not contain all the fields"* -- Wrong. It contains every single field with which the struct _type_ was declared. Whether the fields' values a "zero" or not for a given instance depends on how the instance was initialized, but the fields are there because Go is statically typed, and a struct type's fields do not "disappear"/"reappear" in an instance of the type just because they weren't/were specified in a composite literal.

Comment: Thanks! @mkopriva  You are right, but what I need, can I implement it? Can I intelligently select the fields already assigned to lessee instances to form an array of strings? Even if the fields have zero values.

Comment: You could parse the source code itself (with `go/ast` & co.) to get the list of fields that were explicitly provided in a composite literal, note however that this is generally done by a program separate from the one in the source code (e.g. static analysis). That's the only way to do what you want accurately.

Comment: There's another way but it's not completely "reliable". You could  change the types of the fields to a type whose zero value can be used to infer that the field wasn't initialized. A loose implementation of this would be to utilize pointers, a more strict implementation would be to declare custom unexported types with exported constructors.

Comment: https://go.dev/ref/spec#Composite_literals *"For struct literals the following rules apply:"* ... _"• An element list that contains keys does not need to have an element for each struct field. **Omitted fields get the zero value for that field.**"_

Answer (score 0):

You can write a recursive function to achieve this as shown below and in this function, reflections are used.

**Note:** If we need to read tags and make decisions based on tags, we can customize `getFieldNames`.

```golang
func getFieldNames(i any) (fields []string) {
    fields = make([]string, 0)

    t := reflect.TypeOf(i)
    v := reflect.ValueOf(i)

    for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
        fieldValue := v.Field(i)
        fieldType := t.Field(i)

        if fieldValue.Kind() == reflect.Struct && fieldValue.Type().Name() != "Time" {
            fields = append(fields, getFieldNames(fieldValue.Interface())...)
            continue
        }

        fields = append(fields, fieldType.Name)
    }

    return fields
}
```

**Full example [here](https://go.dev/play/p/0zo4OcoMx55).**